# What's the difference between returning an Iterator and an unmodifiable list?

Tags: java

From what I understand, both are used to return unmodifiable objects, but why would one be used over the other?

Edit: My mistake, Iterators are not unmodifiable. But I'm still unclear on why an Iterator might be used instead of a List.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between a list and an iterator?

Comment: You can start by comparing the [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) and [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interfaces.

Comment: Iterators are not unmodifiable, every time you call `next()` you can get a different results and ultimately it can fail when it runs out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a `List` when you need a list; return an `Iterator` when you need an iterator. They are completely different data structures that serve different purposes.

As an aside, an `Iterator` might be able to modify the underlying collection through the `remove()` method (which removes the last item returned by `next()`).

Edit (in response to OP's edit): You would want to return an `Iterator` if you specifically wanted to prevent client code from seeing the underlying list, or you want to force sequential access to the elements. It's also required that you write an `iterator()` method that returns an `Iterator` when your class implements `Iterable`. There's also the interesting case of returning an `Iterator` that iterates through an undetermined collection of items, that might not even exist in memory until they are requested. (Think, for instance, of state space searching in an AI-based application.)

Comment: What I'm confused about is the difference between the purposes of an (unmodifiable) List and an Iterator. An iterator only allows you to iterate through a list. A list could do that and more.

Comment: Returning either would just give the client the same information, just one more restrictive than the other. What is an example of a situation where returning one would be better than the other?

Comment: @marizal *the same information, just one more restrictive than the other.* That's self-contradictory. Iterators and lists behave very differently and should be used as appropriate. It's like asking why planes and cars both exist if they essentially serve the same purpose of getting from point A to B.

Comment: @marizal - A list cannot iterate. It might look at it when you write an [_enhanced_ `for` _loop_](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) (e.g., `for (String s : someList) { ... }`) but the compiler actually turns that into code that uses an `Iterator`. You can't use an `Iterator` for random access to elements of a `List` by index; you can't ask an `Iterator` for the number of elements; etc. If all you need to do is process each element of a list in sequence, an `Iterator` is the right tool. For just about anything else, you should use the `List` itself.

Comment: An iterator allows you to iterate through things other than lists, @marizal.